# Correctness of inverse surjective homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $G, \overline{G}$ be a groups and $\phi:G\to \overline{G}$ be a surjective homomorphism.

We know that every $\overline{x}\in \overline{G}$ has at least one $x\in G$ such that $\phi(x)=\overline{x}$. Could we claim that inverse mapping $\phi^{-1}:\overline{G}\to G$ is also homomorphism?

Would be very grateful for help.

Comment: the inverse mapping $\phi^{-1}$ does in general not exist!

Comment: @PeterMelech, yes I know that. So even the inverse function does not exist :(

Comment: This is true for *finite groups* since surjections and injections between finite sets are also bijections.

Comment: @KajHansen, not at all. The sets should be identical. In other words, $G=\overline{G}$.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse function $\phi^{-1}$ is not well defined because each $\bar{x} \in \bar{G}$ can have multiple elements in its preimage. If $\phi$ is injective then $\phi^{-1}$ is well defined and a homomorphism. If it is not you can show that $\ker \phi$ is a normal subgroup and that 
$$ \phi^{<-1>}:\bar{G} \to G/\ker \phi$$
is a homomorphism.

Comment: The last mapping you have denoted by $\phi^{-1}$, I guess that $\phi^{-1}$ is not suitable notation for this. Since $\phi^{-1}$ "maps" $\overline{G}$ to $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you choose, for each $y\in \bar{G}$, a preimage $s(y) \in \phi^{-1}\{y\}$ (possibly using some version of the axiom of choice). This defines a map $s\colon \bar{G}\to G$. But this map is not the inverse of $\phi$ in general: all we can say is that $s$ is a *right-inverse*, meaning that $\phi \circ s = \mathrm{id}_\bar{G}$.

Moreover, this right-inverse $s$ can fail to be a group homomorphism. You may want to consider the example
$$\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$
to see that such an $s$ will never be a homomorphism.